# Caching child files in knitr

Tags: r, caching, latex, children, knitr

I have a problem with child files in knitr. The caching works fine, but the dependencies do not work. My sandbox example looks like that:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

<<setup, cache=FALSE>>=
opts_chunk$set(cache=TRUE, autodep=TRUE)
dep_auto() # figure out dependencies automatically
@

<<a>>=
x <- 14
@

<<b>>=
print(x)
@

<<child, child='child.Rnw', eval=TRUE>>=
@

\end{document}
```

With the 'child.Rnw' looking like this:

```
<<child>>=
print(x)
@
```

When I now compile the code, then change x in chunk a and then compile it again: chunk b reacts properly, but the child does not. Am I doing something obviously wrong?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: A new `R` package [`cache`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cache/index.html) might be helpful in this regard.

Answer (score 4):

I thought for a while about this issue, and I find it difficult to fix at the moment. The problem is that the parent document does not really know what is in the child document, and `dep_auto()` does not take the child documents into account when setting the dependency structure. There are two ways to solve this problem. The first one is hackish:

```
knitr:::dep_list$set(a = c('child', 'b'))
```

As you probably know, `:::` means "danger zone" in R. In `knitr`, `dep_list` is the internal object that controls the dependency structure. Both `dep_auto()` and `dep_prev()` rely on this object (similarly that is how the chunk option `dependson` works).

The second way is to write your object into chunk options, e.g.

```
<<child, whatever=x>>=
print(x)
@
```

Read the third section in [the knitr cache page](http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/cache/) for details.

Comment: Many thanks for the thoughts! I tried the second way, added all objects from the parent document to all chunks of the child document and it seems to work out.